# Looking for a google search engine style html/css template

Tags: template

I'm looking for a google search engine style html/css template, paid or unpaid, doesn't need to be exactly the same.  Just sort of a minimal style search engine design template.  Where can I find such templates?

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Are you just trying to emulate the style of Google Search for your own search page? If so, all you have to do is inspect the source of the Google Search page. All the CSS and HTML is right there. Also, templates are designed for specific applications. There's no point in asking for an HTML/CSS template without knowing what sort of template you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it on [Open Source Web Design](http://www.oswd.org/). They have many different layouts. You will probably find one that fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try themeforest.com they have a pretty wide selection

Answer (score 0):

This is a Google style template for WordPress
[Woogle The Google Search Engine Clone](http://ericulous.com/2009/03/18/wp-theme-woogle-the-google-search-engine-clone/)